# Change Series Values to Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart in Excel ("Chart 13"), I also have a named range called "nationals".

I'd like to replace one of the chart's series' Y Values with the named range (the chart has three different series, I'm planning to repeat a similar process for all three).

This is what I have been trying with no success:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 13").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("nationals")
```

I get the following error:

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

I feel like I'm close but can't get to the finish line for the life of me! I appreciate any help.

**EDIT**
This is a line chart (with markers) - sorry that wasn't clear before. Simple version of same situation: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add object to the range like so:

```
Dim MyChart
Set MyChart = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 13").Chart

MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").Range("nationals")
```

Also, as you note, the `ChartObjects().Chart` object has the `SeriesCollection`.

Comment: I get a new error now so that's progress! _Run-time error '-2147352565 (8002000b)': The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type._  This is a line chart so perhaps the values are a different attribute? I appreciate the help.

Comment: OK, fixed, you were missing the `.Chart` from the object. The `SeriesCollection` does not belong to the `ChartObjects` but to its child object `Chart`.

Comment: Thanks for following up - I'll try this when I get to the computer!

Comment: Cool, don't forget to accept and upvote if solved your issue

Comment: Sorry for the delay - so this didn't quite work because I wasn't able to set the chart series to the named range in the new sheet (it's lost when copying and I couldn't set it again with the code).

However, I solved this by creating a template spreadsheet (separate) and copying into it each time and 'saving as'. The template has the chart with the named ranges linked to its series already. This solution worked well. If you add that to your answer I will accept it! Thanks again.